# v-for nested inside another v-for AND an array issue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

OK so this is what I am working with. I have 2 arrays The first array contains an ID number. That ID matches up to the second array minus the presence-chat. string.

Array 1:

```
Rooms: Array
   0: Object
      id: 1
   1: Object
      id: 2
   2: Object
      id: 3
```

Array 2:

```
roomUserCount: Object
   channels: Object
      presence-chat.1: Object
         user_count: 2
      presence-chat.2: Object
         user_count: 3
      presence-chat.3: Object
         user_count: 4
```

What I am trying to figure out is how would I write my v-for command to run through the whole thing. Whats happening before is another v-for that is saying

```
v-for="room in rooms" :key="room.id"
```

Now for the next step nested inside the first v-for I need to run another one to fill in the appropriate data.

the nested code would look like this but I need to fill it in.

```html
<div v-for="" :key="">
   <div v-if="">
      {{ user_count }}
   </div>
   <div v-else="">
      0
   </div>
</div>
```

What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's actually one array (`rooms`) that indexes an object (`roomUserCount`).

Lookup the object by `room.id` in `roomUserCount.channels`. If the object exists, render its `user_count`:

```html
<template>
  <div v-for="room in rooms" :key="room.id">
    <div v-if="roomUserCount.channels['presence-chat.' + room.id]">
      {{ roomUserCount.channels['presence-chat.' + room.id].user_count }}
    </div>
    <div v-else>
      0
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

[demo 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-lookup-object-in-v-for?file=src/App.vue)

Alternatively, you could simplify the template with [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) (`?.`) and [nullish coalescing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) (`??`):

```html
<template>
  <div v-for="room in rooms" :key="room.id">
    {{ roomUserCount.channels['presence-chat.' + room.id]?.user_count ?? 0 }}
  </div>
</template>
```

[demo 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-lookup-object-in-v-for-sb6rov?file=src/App.vue)